# In GWT, How to set a column color without using a style sheet?

Tags: gwt

For some reason, model.cssColor must return a string with "#00FF00"

What i did is override the render method. But it does not work.

```
    Column<PatientTagItemModel,SafeHtml> colorColum = new Column<PatientTagItemModel, SafeHtml>(coloredCell) {
        @Override
        public SafeHtml getValue(PatientTagItemModel object) {

            SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div style='color: " + object.cssColor
                    + "; background-color: "
                    + object.cssColor
                    + ";'>");

            sb.appendHtmlConstant("</div>");

            return sb.toSafeHtml();
        }
    };
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? Does your cell render its content correctly?

Comment: The cell you have here is rendering nothing (opened and closed div, with no content), and has the same background and foreground color (so even if you had content, which you don't, it wouldn't be visible).